How to apply restrictions to DatePickerDialog() using Jetpack Compose
I have a form where I ask users when where they born, but I don't want them to choose future values, but I don't want them to choose future values such as "being born in 2032". ¿Is there a way to apply these filters?
I know there is an ".apply" function, but I wonder how it works.
This is my code:
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun DatePicker(
    selectedDateTime: LocalDateTime?,          // La fecha seleccionada
    onDateChange: (LocalDateTime) -> Unit      // Callback cuando la fecha cambia
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Estado para manejar la fecha seleccionada
    var selectedDate by remember { mutableStateOf(selectedDateTime) }

    // Obtener la fecha actual para establecer valores iniciales
    val now = Clock.System.now().toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault())

    // Mostrar un DatePickerDialog cuando se hace clic en el botón
    val datePickerDialog = remember {
        DatePickerDialog(
            context,
            { _: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
                // Crear un nuevo LocalDateTime basado en la selección
                val newDateTime = LocalDateTime(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth, 0, 0)
                selectedDate = newDateTime
                onDateChange(newDateTime) // Llamar al callback con la fecha nueva
            },
            selectedDate?.year ?: now.year,        // Año inicial
            (selectedDate?.month?.value ?: now.monthNumber) - 1,  // Mes inicial (meses son 0-11)
            selectedDate?.dayOfMonth ?: now.dayOfMonth // Día inicial
        )
    }.apply {
       // ???
    }


    // Botón para seleccionar la fecha
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { datePickerDialog.show() },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        // Mostrar la fecha seleccionada o un texto inicial
        if (selectedDate == null) {
            Text("Seleccionar fecha", color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground)
        } else {
            // Mostrar la fecha seleccionada en formato Día Mes Año
            Text("${selectedDate!!.dayOfMonth} ${selectedDate!!.month.name.lowercase().capitalize()} ${selectedDate!!.year}")
        }
    }

}

I tried something like this:
minDateInMillis?.let { datePicker.datePicker.minDate = it }
but it appears as unresolved reference. Should I try importing something?

Have you tried directly accessing datePicker.maxDate = //max milliseconds in apply block?
